# Install build-essential without apt

Tags: installation, offline

I am not connected to the network and it seems I need build-essentials to get the drivers working. Best I can do is transfer the packages by thumb drive. What is the process for offline installations of the package, and where can I download it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can get the download links from the following command

```
apt-get install --print-uris build-essential
```

This will give you the download links + other details (hash values + etc). You can use these download links to download the packages. Then you can install the packages by double clicking or using the dpkg command (dpkg -i).

Comment: Note that if a package is already in your cache for some reason, the URI won't be printed.

Comment: this still draws on the original issue of 'build-essential' not being installed and this will have the error message of:
"
E:  Unable to locate package build-essential
"

Comment: If the package is already the latest, use "reinstall" to force the print:

sudo apt-get install --reinstall --print-uris build-essential