# No WIFI or LAN on Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 Live CD/USB using Toshiba qosmio x870

Tags: 12.04, wireless, live-usb, lan, toshiba

I recently had issues with secure boot and couldn't boot the Live CD/USB but after disabling secure boot, I was able to 'TRY UBUNTU'. My currently problem is that I can't access WIFI or LAN from either Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 Live CD/USB which I do from Windows 8. Also, the wireless button is able to turn on and off the wireless LED but doesn't find available WIFI. Please, what should I do to get both WIFI and LAN working on Ubuntu using Toshiba qosmio x870?

**UPDATED:**

Here's the output of `lspci`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1213 (rev a1)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
08:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8723
09:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Comment: the x870 seems extremely new... Please can you open up a terminal and issue `lspci` then post the output ?

Comment: Why has this always been a problem?!? Parted Magic has no issues and it's open source. Can't the Ubuntu team take a cue from the Parted Magic team? I'm sure there's other examples besides Parted Magic, I'm just using them as one I know works. I think I've posted this before on this forum too (years ago). Problems like these (which have been solved by other OS's) really hurts Ubuntu's credibility.

Comment: you're absolutely right but I would first commend them for their continuous upgrade on the OS. The beauty of open-source is that we can all help to make our favourite OS way much better and stable for all. I'm glad I'm able to now find the WIFI patch that works whenever I upgrade the kernel. Hopefully soon it will be integrated to the updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution provided in this link [Drivers for Realtek wireless module for Toshiba](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163141/drivers-for-realtek-wireless-module-for-toshiba-c850-a965) by @[izx](https://askubuntu.com/users/58612/izx) solved the wireless problem. Now I'm able to connect to my home wireless and can also see other wireless around from Ubuntu Live CD/USB.

All you need to do is open a terminal, and type/paste one line at a time the following:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-`uname -r`
>
> wget -O- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57056576/DRIVERS/REALTEK/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012.tar.gz | tar -xz
>
> cd rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012
>
> make
>
> sudo make install
>
> sudo modprobe rtl8723e

**Update:** To get my Atheros AR8161 (LAN) working, I did the following:

> apt-get update
> apt-get install linux-generic-lts-quantal

After updating my kernel, my WIFI stopped working. Here is what I did to get it up and running.

For kernel 3.5 and above, use the newer driver version:

> wget -O- http://www.liteon.com/UserFiles/driver/Module/Network/WLAN/RTL/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012.tar.gz | tar -xz
>
> cd rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012
>
> make
>
> sudo make install
>
> sudo modprobe rtl8723e

If it doesn't work then you need to remove rtlwifi because the version that comes with the lower kernel is different from the one the newer rtl8723e is compiled against. That way, the new one will work!

Hence, do the following:

> rmmod rtl8192se and any other rtl that was compiled with the previous kernel.
>
> rmmod rtlwifi

Finally, execute

> sudo modprobe rtl8723e

and your wireless should be up and finding all wireless around.

Answer (score 0):

OK, first answer :) You have an Atheros 8161 - Try the following ! (original post is http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2088179 )

(You'll need an online machine to get the driver to a USB stick and the ubuntu CD inside the x870)

> on the working machine with internet:
>
> `wget -O- http://linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc.tar.bz2` or just get the file with a browser.
>
> then copy that compat-wireless*.tar.bz2 to a usb drive
>
> insert the install cd & usb stick into the machine that needs the
>   drivers and run in terminal (use your thumbdrive in place of
>   USBTHUMB):
>
> `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
>
> `cd /media/USBTHUMB/`
>
> `tar -xvf compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc.tar.bz2`
>
> `cd compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc`
>
> `./scripts/driver-select alx`
>
> `make`
>
> `sudo make install`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Without access to the internet 'sudo apt-get install build-essential' Failed.

> 'ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/PENDRIVE/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc$ ./scripts/driver-select alx'

> 'bash: ./scripts/driver-select: Permission denied'

> 'ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/PENDRIVE/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc$ sudo ./scripts/driver-select alx'

> 'sudo: ./scripts/driver-select: command not found'

Comment: Yes I got the file from another pc which I'm using now. Copied it to another USB stick and did what you saw in the session above.

Comment: I downloaded 'compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc'from my pc with internet and copied it to a USB stick called PENDRIVE. Connected it to the PC with 'TRY UBUNTU'. Without internet on the pc in question, how would 'sudo apt-get install build-essential' work? Thanks.

Comment: 07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)                               08:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8723

Comment: Thanks, I'm using a Ubuntu Live USB. Should that be a problem? When I did the above, I noticed Cdrom with Ubuntu 12.04 'Precise Pangolin' is already ticked.

Comment: Ok, this is because build-essential is not part of the official Ubuntu CDROM ! ( !! ) I am sorry but you'll have to do some work by hand : http://askubuntu.com/questions/140077/install-build-essentials-without-apt

Comment: Thanks a lot for your assistance. I'm in between returning this nice Toshiba qosmio x870 or getting this fixed. I hope I find a solution soon. Thanks Martin.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested link. :~/Downloads$ apt-get install --print-uris install build-essentials.......
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package install
E: Unable to locate package build-essentials

Comment: it is *build-essential* actually, there was a typo error in the other Question I have just corrected.

Comment: Now I get: E: Unable to locate package install. Thanks

Comment: I have been able to access wireless using the solution I found and provided. The next step is detecting Windows 8. You mentioned that if _Ubuntu Live USB_ boots in **UEFI** mode then it should detect Windows 8 during installation. I don't want to Erase disk and install Ubuntu but install alongside windows 8. I will create another question for this. Thanks.