# Ubuntu 12.04 - Not recognizing Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet

Tags: 12.04, ethernet, atheros

I built my own computer about a month ago and loaded Windows 7 on it, and then decided to put Ubuntu 12.04 on instead. It doesn't recognize my ethernet cable, and I cannot get any internet what-so-ever. I would like to know which drivers to download. I have 32-bit, if that helps. I do have an external HDD that I can transfer between computers with. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

When did you download the CD image? If this was over a week ago, then downloading and installing the latest 12.04 point release (12.04.2, released on Feb 14) is probably the simplest solution in your situation.

From 12.04.2 onward, the LTS releases will run on more recent kernels. Their [LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) will keep the kernel and X stack in sync with stable versions from newer releases (Quantal, Raring, S). Quantal's kernel (3.5.0) has built-in support for the alx driver, which is what you need.

For those  currently on 12.04 LTS: updating from 12.04.1 or 12.04 will *not* enable the LTS Enablement Stack. To do this, install the **linux-generic-lts-quantal** and/or **xserver-xorg-lts-quantal** packages.

```
apt-get update    
apt-get install linux-generic-lts-quantal
```

... was all I needed to do to get my Atheros AR8162 working.

Comment: Thanks! After doing that my Atheros AR8162 also started working but my Wireless: _Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8723_ stopped working. I see ***-network UNCLAIMED** when I run `sudo lshw -c network`.

Comment: I was able to get it working by updating **rtl8723e** to a newer driver that supports _kernel 3.5 and above_. I explained all I did in this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/226125/no-wifi-or-lan-on-ubuntu-12-04-or-12-10-live-cd-usb-using-toshiba-qosmio-x870/227046#227046). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Settings > Additional Drivers
2. Wait a minute the system will being update the repository
3. Then, all support drivers in Ubuntu will be available in list
4. Choose and install the driver based on the device
5. If your device that you mean not shown on the list, it's possible your
   device is not supported for Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Problem is, it's not a device, I'm trying to get ethernet access. I have no internet connection at all, so I just need the drivers and the code to install them. Thanks.

Comment: actually the problem is on your device that no support with Ubuntu, and also Ubuntu doesn't provide driver for your device.

Try to connect with wireless connection like usb modem then do in order.